# How to define more than 1 category in Eclipse properties view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

we are able to create a `PropertyDescriptor` with a single Category, which allows properties view to have Many categories.
   But, I want to assign a category to another category, Like having subcategories. Please, let me know how to do it.

Went need to display the properties as below structure. Please, let me know how to do it?
[image]

Comment: To my knowledge the properties view does not support sub-categories. [Take control of your properties](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Properties-View/properties-view.html) and [The Eclipse Tabbed Properties View](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html) do not mention nested categories either.

Comment: Thanks Herrmann for the reply. The resource you provided had the clue for showing sub-categories.

Comment: If you would like to share your findings so that others can adopt your solution consider to post an answer.